# How to write special charecter into the text fie from batch script

Tags: batch-file

I want to write characters like '<', '>'  into the text file from MS DOS script ?

How do I do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precede each special character with a carat (^), such as:

```
ECHO ^> > YourFile.txt
```